# Proving on $\lim_{x\to5}\frac{x+1}{x-2}=2$

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

Prove $$\lim_{x\to5}\frac{x+1}{x-2}=2$$
with the $\delta,\epsilon$ limit proof.
Find a $\delta$ for any $\epsilon$ which $|x-5|<\delta$ leads to $|\frac{x+1}{x-2} - 2| < \epsilon$.

I used $x-2 \neq 0$ and simplified $|\frac{x+1}{x-2} - 2| < \epsilon$ to $|\frac{x-5}{x-2}| < \epsilon$. But I don't know how to use $|x-5|<\delta$ now. Is the simplification of the inequation usefull?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is advisable to show your work before asking for help. Please let us know what you have tried so that we can better help you.

Comment: You might be interested in Angelo's comment below my answer, and my subsequent response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is useful to simplify $\displaystyle{\left|\frac{x+1}{x-2}-2\right|<\varepsilon}$ to $\displaystyle{\left|\frac{x-5}{x-2}\right|<\varepsilon}$. The next step is to write this as
$$
\frac{|x-5|}{|x-2|}<\varepsilon \, .
$$
Let's begin by requiring that $|x-5|<1$, so that we can come up with a lower bound of $|x-2|$. If $|x-5|<1$, then $-1<x-5<1$, and so $2<x-2<4$. Since $2$ and $x-2$ are both positive, we can take reciprocals of the inequality $2<x-2$ while reversing the direction of the inequality sign. This yields
$$
\frac{1}{2}>\frac{1}{x-2} \, ;
$$
multiplying both sides by $|x-5|$, this becomes
$$
\frac{|x-5|}{x-2}<\frac{|x-5|}{2} \, .
$$
So if we can force $\displaystyle{\frac{|x-5|}{2}}$ to be smaller than $\varepsilon$, then it will certainly be the case that $\displaystyle{\frac{|x-5|}{x-2}=\frac{|x-5|}{|x-2|}}$ is smaller than $\varepsilon$. This amounts to requiring that $|x-5|<2\varepsilon$. Hence, if $|x-5|<1$ and $|x-5|<2\varepsilon$, then
$$
\frac{|x-5|}{x-2}<\varepsilon \, ,
$$
which is what we wanted. Take $\delta=\min(1,2\varepsilon)$. Notice that I didn't consider what I should pick as my $\delta$ until the very end of the proof.

---

Response to comment:
@Angelo: It's not wrong—it's just that when you come up with an epsilon-delta proof yourself, very often you only pick the $\delta$ at the end. My answer tries to mimic the thought process that I would go through. Of course, you can rewrite it more neatly at the end. If $|x-5|<1$ and $|x-5|<2\varepsilon$, then
\begin{align}
x-2>2 &\implies\frac{1}{x-2}<\frac{1}{2} \\[5pt]
&\implies\frac{|x-5|}{x-2}<\frac{|x-5|}{2}<\frac{2\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon \, .
\end{align}

Comment: I did not consider what I should pick as my $\delta$ until the very end of the proof either, but in my answer I preferred to write $\delta$ at the beginning so that my proof was neater and similar to the formal definition of limit. Do you think it is wrong ?

Comment: @Angelo: Not at all—see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

For any $\,\varepsilon>0\,$ there exists $\,\delta=\dfrac{3\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon}\in\big(0,3\big)$ such that for all $\,x\in\mathbb R\;\land\;x\ne2\;\land\;|x-5|<\delta\;$ it results that

$|x-2|\geqslant3-|x-5|>3-\delta>0\;\;,$

consequently ,

$\begin{align}\left|\dfrac{x+1}{x-2}-2\right|&=\left|\dfrac{x-5}{x-2}\right|<\dfrac\delta{3-\delta}=\dfrac{\frac{3\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon}}{3-\frac{3\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon}}=\\&=\dfrac{3\varepsilon}{3+3\varepsilon-3\varepsilon}=\varepsilon\;.\end{align}$

Hence ,

for any $\,\varepsilon>0\,$ there exists $\,\delta=\dfrac{3\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon}>0\;$ such that for all $\,x\in\mathbb R\;\land\;x\ne2\;\land\;|x-5|<\delta\;$ it results that $\;\left|\dfrac{x+1}{x-2}-2\right|<\varepsilon\;.$

By definition of limit, it means that

$\lim\limits_{x\to5}\dfrac{x+1}{x-2}=2\;.$